# resizable form in visual studio 2005 can only be made bigger, not smaller again

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2005

I'm working on an old project from an other developer, and can't get something solved ...

I have a form in visual studio 2005 which is resizable. But when I resize at runtime, it only allows me to make it bigger, not smaller. It has nothing to do with minimumsize, because after making it larger, I also can't return to the original size. Very strange :-)

Someone here who had something similar?

On the form is a splitcontainer which is located 2 pixels from the border of the form.

thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as usual, found the solution within minutes after posting a question ;-)

setting AutoSize to false, solved the problem!